# Polygons and keys

Tags: python, dictionary, polygons

hi I am having trouble with this one problem

Given a variable, `polygon_sides`, that is associated with a dictionary that maps names of polygons to number of sides, create a new dictionary that maps number of sides to polygon names, and associate it with a variable `n_polygons`.

my current code

```
for n_polygons in polygon_sides:
    polygon_sides={n_polygons[]:polygon_sides}
```

the only error it gives me are syntax errors.

do i have to rearrange the whole problem??

Comment: You have to read a tutorial in the first place. Programming is not about throwing symbols around hoping the interpreter will makes sense of it.

Comment: @Julien these days it appears to be about hoping that some stranger will write the code for you. I pity these people when they have to write code that's more than a single line long.

Answer (score 2):

It's a one-liner. You need a loop in the expression to get all the elements.

```
n_polygons = {v:k for k,v in polygon_sides.items()}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've used `n_polygons` in your code already. My understanding is that you want to swap the key-value pairs in the dict. Try this instead

```
n_polygons  = dict((v,k) for k,v in polygon_sides.iteritems())
```